# Loaded txt file displaying incorrectly in FlowDocumentReader

Tags: c#, wpf

When I read a txt file into FlowDocumentReader it looks messy comparing with the original content in txt file.

[image]
[image]

Also I have tried to use different containers for displaying text but always get the same result.

[Update]The problem was solved by changing the current font to monospace.

Comment: Please post your code and insert the contents of the images as text via editing your post. It also looks like this may just be an issue of the processed text not using a monospace font (which misaligns everything), so I'd take that into consideration as well.

Comment: use a monospace font